# Bug with elastic scrolling and menu bar in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I want to set up a menu bar like you see her in JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gvjeyywa/21/

There it works exactly the way I want it to … But on the webpage it has a bug, I think it's because of the elastic scrolling in OSX … On scrolling down the menu bar should slide in from the top to set up on top:0px, being fixed there… But if you scroll back to top and the elastic scrolling scrolls higher than the body is… the menu jumps too high…

Here see the live example:
http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/index.php/projects

on iOS it's a complete mess too…

Here is the JS Code:

```
         var bitFlag = false;
    var isActive = true;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var timeoutId;
    $navigation = $("#navigation");
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var intWindowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var intElementBottom = $navigation.offset().top + $navigation.height();
        if (intWindowTop > lastScrollTop) {
            isActive = true;
            if (!bitFlag) {
                $navigation.css("position", "absolute").css("top", intWindowTop + "px");
                bitFlag = true;
            }
            if (timeoutId) {
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            }
            timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                if (intWindowTop > intElementBottom) {
                    intDelayTime = setTimeout(function () {
                        if (isActive) {
                            $navigation.animate({ top: intWindowTop + "px" }, {
                                duration: 800,
                                step: function () {
                                    if ($(window).scrollTop() < $navigation.offset().top) {
                                        $(this).stop(true,true);
                                    }
                                },
                                complete: function () {
                                    intDelayTime2 = setTimeout(function () {
                                        $("#navigation").css("position", "fixed").css("top", "0px");
                                        bitFlag = false;
                                        isActive = false;
                                    }, 1);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, 500);
                }
            }, 100);
        } else {
            $navigation.css("position", "fixed").css("top", "0px");
            bitFlag = false;
            isActive = false;
        }
        lastScrollTop = intWindowTop;
    });
```

And this is the CSS:

```
 #navigation {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index:999;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Does someone have an idea? Unfortunately I'am a bloody starter in JS… I am thankful for any help…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is this: `intWindowTop > lastScrollTop`.
this value is true, when you scroll into the negative area, that comes with webkit.

so you have to check, if the value is positive via `intWindowTop > 0`

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var intWindowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var intElementBottom = $navigation.offset().top + $navigation.height();
    if ( intWindowTop > lastScrollTop && intWindowTop > 0 ) {
      //...
    } else { 
      //...
    }
```

note that i removed the variable "event" as well. you dont use it, so why declare it..?

Comment: Yes this is it! Perfect!

Comment: Works perfect now… On Ipad its still a mess, but I think this is fixable too

Comment: as far as i know, the ipad scroll event isn't fired when you scroll, but when scrolling stops. so maybe fix the element for mobile devices (or touch devices?) and skip this efx?